# How to delete in an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have an array which I store different classes which again hold different arrays. All arrays are defined as NSMutabelArrays.

When I want to delete an object in an array, my app crashes. This is my code:

```
NSLog(@"string to be deleted:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabReference] objectAtIndex:tid]);
NSLog(@"string to be deleted:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabColours] objectAtIndex:tid]);
NSLog(@"string to be deleted:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabTitles] objectAtIndex:tid]);

[[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabReference] removeObjectAtIndex:tid];
[[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabColours] removeObjectAtIndex:tid];
[[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabTitles] removeObjectAtIndex:tid];
```

And this is the console output:

```
2011-05-01 22:03:40.788 M[61452:207] string to be deleted:2
2011-05-01 22:03:40.789 M[61452:207] string to be deleted:Orange
2011-05-01 22:03:40.791 M[61452:207] string to be deleted:Art
2011-05-01 22:03:40.806 M[61452:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. There is obviously something in the array, so it shouldn't be 0. I mean it is the ONLY thing stored in the array at the moment, but that shouldn't be a problem, I guess?

I'd be very grateful for any help on this.

---

**EDIT:**

I think I haven't provided enough code. This is the method in which I set up myLibrary:

```
-(void) setupLibrary {

myLibrary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NoteBook *newNoteBook = [[NoteBook alloc] init];

newNoteBook.titleName = @"TEST";

NSMutableArray *ttArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ttArray addObject:@"Art"];

NSMutableArray *tcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tcArray addObject:@"Orange"];

NSMutableArray *trArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[trArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]];

newNoteBook.tabTitles = ttArray;
newNoteBook.tabColours = tcArray;
newNoteBook.tabReference = trArray;

[myLibrary addObject:newNoteBook];
currentNoteBookNumber = 0;

[newNoteBook release];
[ttArray release];
[tcArray release];
[trArray release];
```

}

Now it appears that if I delete, for instance, one object in the tabTitles array (e.g. "Art"), I delete the entire newNoteBook object. I.e. once I delete a string in tabTitles, all other strings at the same position in tabColours or tabReference will be deleted as well. Why is this so?

The following code will crash after I successfully deleted the string @ position 0 in an array in my class which is stored in another array:

```
    NSLog(@"string deleted:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] tabReference] objectAtIndex:0]);
[[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] tabReference] removeObjectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"string deleted:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] tabColours] objectAtIndex:0]);
[[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] tabColours] removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Hmmm can you duplicate your three nslogs and put them inbetween of every removal? And dump the count of the array in it as well.

Comment: Can you give more code? Like where you create and insert the objects? And put the entire method in which you have the above code. It may help.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: I updated the code according to your suggestions. Also, I've given more code on how I set up the library. Your help and patience is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Cyprian: I've edited my post and given more code. Thanks for your help and I think you're right in your suggested answer below - but I still don't really understand what the issue is...

Comment: @n.evermind still need more info. Where do you call your remove code. Please add that method and also is your code crashes after NSLog or after the removal? And what is the crash exactly.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Thanks for your thoughts! I actually solved the problem with Cyprian's help... I tried to delete the information which was needed to display certain buttons. So I needed to remove the buttons before I deleted the information... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error

```
-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0
```

is telling that you are trying to get an object at index 0 not that you want to remove it. So I think what you did is you called the method where you have your reading and removing code 2 times in a row. Try to see it that is the case.

Comment: Actually, your suggestions to post more information was actually the solution!! I realised that I am calling the removeObject method from a method which is dependent on the information being deleted. I set up a couple of buttons which need the information in the array to be displayed, and I obviously can't delete the information needed for the buttons BEFORE removing the buttons which are dependent on that information. Thanks so much for your help and questions!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what's the problem here, but you should consider to keep your arrays safe:

```
if([yourArray count] > tid) {
    [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex.tid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with more code - don't know if you can be bothered to have another look. If so, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!